# avoid connection overhead to database in php

Tags: php, odbc

how can the session be handled in php for database connection so as to avoid the overhead of connecting every time to the database? 
Note:connection to the database is through odbc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at persistent connections (example #4) at the [PHP docu](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php).

Answer (score 1):

Maintain thr database object from your very first query. Some people use $_GLOBAL but that has a few implications certain developers arnt comfortable with.  Personally I use it because it's the simplest approach.

Comment: can u elaborate? as in how can this be done if i have to use $conn on next page if $ conn holds returned resource from odbc_connect().

Comment: Oh no sorry but for separate requests, you'll need to establish a new connection. This is because web requests are stateless. Persistent connections are a solution here but from my experience very difficult to scale. You should look at memcache if you are getting  performance issues from many connections.